# Why I can't install Windows Phone 8 update 3 emulators?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sdk, visual-studio-2013

I tried to install Windows Phone 8 SDK Update 3 emulators and got error which says that I'm not installed Visual Studio 2013, but I installed Visual Studio 2013 Professional also I installed Visual Studio Update 1. Any ideas how to solve that problem? I installed Windows Phone 8 SDK from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=257234&clcid=0x409

Comment: Why didn't you install Windows Phone 8 SDK as part of the VS 2013 setup? Or is that only in the Ultimate version?

Comment: Okay, now the problem is when I try to launch emulator it says that my PC is missing Windows 8 Professional (64-bit), but I'm using Windows 8.1 Professional 64-bit version, any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: Have you try to install the Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 ? These update fixe the different compatibility issues with W8.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you also have Visual Studio 2012 installed, have you installed VS2012 Update 4?
From the requirements notes: "This update requires either Visual Studio 2012 with Update 4 or later, or Visual Studio 2013."

I have nearly the same setup as you (Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit, VS2012 Pro + Update 4, VS2013 Pro + Update 2 RC) and all WP8 Emulators work fine here (all = WP8, WP8 Update 3, WP8.1).